# Siegebreaker - Interaction between Bull Rush and Overrun

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat-maneuver, archetype

The [Siegebreaker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/paizo---fighter-archetypes/siegebreaker-fighter-archetype) fighter archetype grants an ability called Breaker Momentum, which says:

> At 2nd level, when a siegebreaker successfully bull rushes a foe, he can attempt an overrun combat maneuver check against that foe as a free action.

This is confusing to me.  If I successfully bull rush someone, they are pushed back. However, over run involves moving through other spaces. How do these maneuvers interact? Part of my confusion stems from over run requiring movement, while bull rush does not.

Comment: O, my. I can imagine that special ability was originally at least twice that length when somebody said, "Aw, c'mon, just say it this way—we're late for bowling."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you [bull rush](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Bull-Rush) someone, "You can move with the target if you wish". If you do so, Breaker Momentum makes you able to attempt to [overrun](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Overrun) and so continue your movement.

RAW, as overrun needs to be part of a movement or a charge, you have to use you movement action in the process.

Answer (score 2):

When you make a successful [bull rush](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Bull-Rush) maneuver, the target is pushed back 5 feet plus 5 feet for every 5 by which you exceed the opponent's CMD.  This means that you can still have movement remaining by the time your opponent has stopped being pushed by the bull rush maneuver.  This is saying you can attempt to continue your movement past the foe by attempting an [overrun](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Overrun) check, allowing you to get behind them for flanking, not providing them soft cover from archers on your side, cutting off their retreat, etc...

Sidenote: I agree with Hey I Can Chan's comment that this class ability was probably originally much more detailed, but was eventually cut down to what it is now for word and page count in Pathfinder Player Companion: Heroes of the Street.